# Docker MEAN.JS can't set to run in 'PRODUCTION' mode

Tags: node.js, docker, meanjs

In the Mean.Js Docker file I've set ENV var to production from development:

```
ENV NODE_ENV production
```

When starting the docker container, in the console output it shows that it is running in "Development" environment.

I've re-started the docker container as:

```
docker run -e "NODE_ENV=production"-i -t --name www1 --link mongodb:db_1 -p 80:3000 somecompany/meansite
```

Again, the output from grunt in the console shows that it is running in "development mode"

so, I did:

```
docker exec -it www1 bash printenv
```

And confirmed that the NODE_ENV is in fact set to production:

```
NODE_ENV=production
```

Can't seem to understand why the Mean.Js does not run in "production" mode but always defaults to "development" even when the NODE_ENV variable is set to production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that feature had not been implemented yet. 
FedeG added a separate Dockerfile for production:

[Github issue Tracking for Docker Prod](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/issues/1431)